# Migrate metadata from github to github enterprise

Tags: git, github, migration, data-migration

I see that https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.0/admin/articles/moving-a-repository-from-github-com-to-github-enterprise/ says you can use the api to transfer metadata like issues, comments, and pull requests.

I searched around to see if anyone has done this before, but couldn't find any answers. I'll be working on this myself, but there will be some tricky issues. For example, a closed pull request with a deleted branch seems nontrivial to add, as the api won't let you add a pull request from a nonexisting branch. However, if I skip these, the pull request number will be off, which will then be incorrectly referenced from the comments.

Thanks!

Comment: Github 2.3 has a tool that now does this for you!
https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.3/admin/guides/migrations/